# Panel Pop-Up Dialog

Tags: python, holoviz-panel

A bit of context (because science): I have written a [panel gui](https://github.com/Lewisc2/LaserTRAMZ/tree/main) to reduce data gathered with an instrument, and I am repeating the process for different instrument. However, the new instrument is a bit more complex in terms of its detectors.
Currently I (and other users of the open source program) am able to just import raw data as a pandas dataframe and put it into a param dataframe just fine. However, for the updated version I need to be able to prompt the user to input their analytes and the detector type that measured that particular analyte. I'd like to generate a pop-up upon data upload in order to do this. I looked around a bit but could not find a straightforward way to do this and I'd prefer not to use css. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
    @pn.depends('file_path',watch=True)
    def _uploadfile(self):
        if self.file_path != 'Insert File Path':
            df = pd.read_excel(self.file_path,sheet_name='Data')
            self.input_data = df
            self.input_data.drop(self.input_data.index[0:75],axis=0)
            # begin where I am looking for help
            generate pop_up ....
            # end where I'm looking for a solution, continue data wrangling below
```

A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

No obvious solution and believe I will need to find a complete workaround that will require a complete revamp to something that already works well with one caveat.

Comment: I never worked with panel, but [here's a discussion](https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/can-i-use-create-a-modal-dialog-in-panel/1207/18) from last year which might give you some ideas on how to approach this task.